# Opencv color mapping with direct pixel access

Tags: c++, opencv

I have a gray scale image that I want to display in color by mapping the gray scale values with a color palette (like colormap in Matlab).

I managed to do it by using OpenCV *cvSet2D* function, but I would like to access to the pixels directly for performance reasons.

But when I do that the image has strange colors. I tried to set the colors in different orders (RGB, BGR,…) but can’t seem to get around it.

There is my code:

```
    IplImage* temp = cvCreateImage( cvSize(img->width/scale,img->height/scale), IPL_DEPTH_8U, 3 );
for (int y=0; y<temp->height; y++)
{
    uchar* ptr1 = (uchar*) ( temp->imageData + y * temp->widthStep );
    uchar* ptr2 = (uchar*) ( img->imageData + y * img->widthStep );

    for (int x=0; x<temp->width; x++)
    {
        CvScalar v1;

        int intensity = (int)ptr2[x];
        int b=0, g=0, r=0;
        r = colormap[intensity][0];
        g = colormap[intensity][1];
        b = colormap[intensity][2];

        if (true)
        {
            ptr1[3*x]   = b;
            ptr1[3*x+1] = g;
            ptr1[3*x+2] = r;
        }
        else
        {
            v1.val[0] = r;
            v1.val[1] = g;
            v1.val[2] = b;
            cvSet2D(temp, y, x, v1);
        }
    }
}
```

Change the if (true) to if (false) for different pixel access.

The correct result is with cvSet2D:

[image: enter code here]

The wrong result with the direct memory access:

[image]

Thank you for your help

Comment: Can't see any mistake right now. The correct byte order should be BGR inside `imageData`. How does the image change if you change the byte order? It should change, otherwise you're doing something wrong. Try to render only one color (leave other channels at 0/black). And see if they fit. Alignment seems to be correct but I'm a bit confused about the hard contrast around the corners.

Comment: I found out my error... In fact it's RGB but that wasn't the problem, I had color values at 256 instead of 255... Really sorry... I guess asking the question helped me found the answer.

Comment: Ahh ... okay. That explains the hard contrast (due to overflows and such). :)

Comment: Am I wrong when I say, that this question has been tagged a bit faulty? IplImage is from the old c syntax right?

Comment: no iplImage is a part of openCV but it has been replaced with CV::Mat now.

Comment: Could you give the definition of img? Des img have only one band?

Comment: Please close question then. People spend time solving it.

Comment: Please close this question. i spent a lot of time answering it, and now just found out that you have solved your problem.

Comment: @david: +1 for illustration haha. You can post your answer below and actually close the question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm posting this to close the question like asked in the comments of my question.

The answer was:

I found out my error... In fact it's RGB but that wasn't the problem, I had color values at 256 instead of 255... Really sorry... I guess asking the question helped me found the answer

Thank you

Answer (score 5):

I have done something similar for coloring depth maps from Microsoft Kinect Sensor. The code I used for converting a grayscale depth map into color image will work for what you are trying to do. You may require slight modifications as in my case the depth values were in the range 500 to 2000, and I had to rescale them.

The function for colouring a grayscale image into colour image is:

```
void colorizeDepth( const Mat& gray, Mat& rgb)
{
        double maxDisp= 255;
        float S=1.f;
        float V=1.f ;

        rgb.create( gray.size(), CV_8UC3 );
        rgb = Scalar::all(0);

    if( maxDisp < 1 )
            return;

    for( int y = 0; y < gray.rows; y++ )
        {
            for( int x = 0; x < gray.cols; x++ )
            {
                uchar d = gray.at<uchar>(y,x);
                unsigned int H = 255 - ((uchar)maxDisp - d) * 280/ (uchar)maxDisp;    
            unsigned int hi = (H/60) % 6;

            float f = H/60.f - H/60;
                float p = V * (1 - S);
                float q = V * (1 - f * S);
                float t = V * (1 - (1 - f) * S);

            Point3f res;

                if( hi == 0 ) //R = V,  G = t,  B = p
                    res = Point3f( p, t, V );
                if( hi == 1 ) // R = q, G = V,  B = p
                    res = Point3f( p, V, q );
                if( hi == 2 ) // R = p, G = V,  B = t
                    res = Point3f( t, V, p );
                if( hi == 3 ) // R = p, G = q,  B = V
                    res = Point3f( V, q, p );
                if( hi == 4 ) // R = t, G = p,  B = V
                    res = Point3f( V, p, t );
                if( hi == 5 ) // R = V, G = p,  B = q
                    res = Point3f( q, p, V );

                uchar b = (uchar)(std::max(0.f, std::min (res.x, 1.f)) * 255.f);
                uchar g = (uchar)(std::max(0.f, std::min (res.y, 1.f)) * 255.f);
                uchar r = (uchar)(std::max(0.f, std::min (res.z, 1.f)) * 255.f);

                rgb.at<Point3_<uchar> >(y,x) = Point3_<uchar>(b, g, r);     

        }
        }
}
```

For an input image which looks like this:

[image]

Output of this code is:

[image]